# display more information from SQL table on a different page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table - called sports- that consists of:

- event_id
- event_name
- category
- level
- additional

Which is showing in my PHP document as:
[image]

- event_name
- category
- level

What I want, is when a user clicks on 'more information', they are taken to a page that displays the content of 'additional' in the db table - but only for the sport that has been selected.

```
$query =
"SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport_id = $sport_id";
 $result = mysql_query($query);


echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['sport_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['category'] . "</td><td>" .           $row['level'] . "</td></tr>";
echo <tr><td>" . $row['level'] . "</td></tr>
}
echo "</table>";
```

What is the best what to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code showing what you tried?

Comment: Also, which [**SQL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) are you using? MySQL, MsSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.? You haven't properly tagged your question.

Comment: I am using MySQL.
I have a href on the 'more details', which links to 'additionalInfo.php', this page has:

$query =
"SELECT * FROM sports WHERE event_id = ['event_id']";
$result = mysql_query($query);

 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['sport_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['category'] . "</td><td>" . $row['level'] . "</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";

Comment: Show us your code then.

Comment: Show your code in your question, not in the "comments" box.

Comment: I posted something for you below.

Comment: Wait, I have to edit my answer. However, I need to see more code. I don't know how you're setting `$sport_id` and where it's coming from, an HTML form? An `href` from `GET`?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sports WHERE sport_id = $sport_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<p>'.$row['additional'].' </p>';
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.